# Where to store URLs in Angular2 App?

Tags: angular

Where to store URLs (to be used in HTTP services) in an Angular2 app?

**Update (explained more):**

I am calling ASP.net Web Api from Angular2. Currently I have to use the url in every service and therefore when need to change the domain, it is difficult to change all service. Can we set some configuration file to get the baseUrl/domain and append the rest of the url?

Comment: not at all explanatory..what do you want ?

Comment: What URL? What server do you want to call? Why do you want to store it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, server technology doesn't matter to me. I have explained the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @RajeshPatel question has been updated.

Comment: Note that many times, the URL is not needed, because you can just use /foo/bar, and thus target the URL where the web page comes from.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for commenting. My Angular2 App is on a different domain than the Web api.

Answer (score 1):

You can just inject a configuration value

```ts
@NgModel({
  providers: [ /*other providers */ {provide: 'serverUrl', useValue: 'http://x.y.com'}],
  ...
```

```ts
class MyServiceOrComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('serverUrl') private serverUrl:string) {}
```

Instead of `'serverUrl'` you can also use [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html) (preferred)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can we use anything in typescript like a static class in C#, and use it as AppSettings.urls.apiBaseUrl ?

Comment: Sure, but DI is used in Angular2 for a purpose. For example it allows you to replace the injected values easily in unit tests which is cumbersome with static classes. If you don't care you can just use static properties of an `AppSettings` class.